# Current pathname in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular-routing

Even though I am on the `/login` page, the URL in ActivatedRoute is empty. Here's the code. I tried both refreshing the page and going to it through routing. I want the current activated pathname.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.url.subscribe(x => console.log(x.join(','))); //empty string
    console.log(this.router.url); // logs '/'
  }
}
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong ? I know this can be done via `window.location`. Just wanted to avoid that and use router instead so that I can have the updated pathname always using observable.

Here's my routerConfig

```js
const routerConfig: Route[] = [{
  path: '',
  redirectTo: '/home',
  pathMatch: 'full'
}, {
  path: 'home',
  loadChildren: 'app/home/home.module#HomeModule'
}, {
  path: 'login',
  loadChildren: 'app/login/login.module#LoginModule'
}];
```

There is no server-side code yet. Everything is on client side.

Angular => 2.0.0 final
Router => 3.0.0

Comment: Is /login a client-side route (configured through the angular2 router rather than a route defined on the server) and not a redirect / default?  The activated route's url is just the route segments which match the client-side route.  So it won't include the full path if, say, your server maps http://yourdomain/login to the root of your Angular2 app.

Comment: @StevenLuke I have updated the question.

Comment: And the AppComponent you show is mapped to the `` route of the routing imported in your LoginModule?